# Repo is not being linked with its parent repo after .git folder is removed

Tags: git, github

So we have a parent repo that has two other repo's inside of it.  For example we have a website which has one repo, and then 2 profiles inside of that website that each are their own repos.

One of the profiles is extremely out of date, but instead of deleting it since there are still some dependencies, we just removed the .git folder from the repo in order to allow us to not worry about pushing updates to this outdated module and breaking everything.

Right now, when we try to do git clones or pulls of the parent repo (which contains this profile repo we deleted the .git folder for), the repo whose .git folder we deleted inside of the server is not pulled with it.

The parent git folder has a reference to the old repo that says something like @ 1b23727.

Would deleting the .git folder for this profile inside of the server cause the repo to no longer be pulled when cloning the parent repo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're dealing with a submodule.

If you `git submodule` from the parent repo you'll git will output the submodules configured.

To pull recreate the submodule(s), do `git submodule update --init -recursive`.

To clone the parent repo and include the submodules, `git clone --recursive <remote uri>`

Comment: Without readding the git folder, is it possible to make it so that I don't have to run 3 commands in order to get the repo?  With the .git repo it worked as just 1 git clone I believe.

Comment: You need to use `git clone --recursive <remote uri>` to get them all in one step. Reference: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#Cloning-a-Project-with-Submodules

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks so much!